# What does the openmpi error "Failing at address: 0x0" mean?

Tags: runtime-error, mpi, openmpi

I am debugging a program, and think I narrowed it down to an openmpi issue. Knowing what this error message means would help me in knowing where to probe further. This package runs fine on linux but produces the below error on osx.

Does anyone understand this runtime error message?

```
[kilojouless-MacBook-Pro:03377] *** Process received signal ***
[kilojouless-MacBook-Pro:03377] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[kilojouless-MacBook-Pro:03377] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[kilojouless-MacBook-Pro:03377] Failing at address: 0x0
[kilojouless-MacBook-Pro:03377] *** End of error message ***
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: The error message means that some piece of code is trying to dereference a null pointer*. Without additional information including an [mcve], I doubt anyone could give you any further help. * technically there could be other reasons, but this is most likely.

Comment: For now it does not look like an openMP issue - I would suggest compiling everything with -g flag and then debug the app with gdb - then you'll know the line where everything crashes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chaosit. Zulan, the idea behind my post is not requesting a solution to my specific problem, but to add to the documentation around this error message. Googling this error has yielded confusing results.

Comment: Then this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/620382)